# Are side-channels possible in KDFs

Tags: side-channel-attack

Are KDFs such as PKDF2 and HKDF vulnerable to side-channel attacks such as static and dynamic power analysis including the hash type used internally?

Comment: A try [Attacking scrypt via Cache Timing Side-Channel](https://crypto.stanford.edu/cs359c/17sp/projects/MarkAnderson.pdf)

Comment: Also the Password Hashing Contest mailing list archive[1] has lots of discussion about sidechannel resistance of the various password hashing function candidates, most of which are KDFs. So the short answer to this question would be "yes".

 [1] https://lists.openwall.net/phc-discussions/

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, a side-channel attack by definition doesn't attack a KDF but a specific implementation of it. An example of an implementation would be the way macOS turns a user's password to a disk encryption key with PKDF2. A gZip application may execute the PKDF2 in a slightly different fashion.

The answer to your question is yes, because you can never know if a developer made a mistake, or something like that. If that isn't what you meant please clarify.